# Is it possible to associate data with a running process?

Tags: windows, winapi, process

As the title says, I want to associate a random bit of data (ULONG) with a running process on the local machine. I want that data persisted with the process it's associated with, not the process thats reading & writing the data. Is this possible in Win32?

Comment: Can you give more information about what you're trying to do? As written, I have no idea what you have in mind.

Comment: What are you trying to do? I sense an XY problem here.

Comment: Why?  ([Only two to go.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem#comment436926_66378))

Comment: If you just want to share memory between two processes, look into creating a memory mapped file. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes but it can be tricky. You can't access an arbitrary memory address of another process and you can't count on shared memory because you want to do it with an arbitrary process.

### The tricky way

What you can do is to create a **window** (with a special and known name) inside the process you want to *decorate*. See the end of the post for an alternative solution without windows.

- First of all you have to get a handle to the process with `OpenProcess`.
- Allocate memory with `VirtualAllocEx` in the other process to hold a short method that will create a (hidden) window with a special known name.
- Copy that function from your own code with `WriteProcessMemory`.
- Execute it with `CreateRemoteThread`.

Now you need a way to identify and read back this memory from another process other than the one that created that. For this you simply can find the window with that known name and you have your *holder* for a small chunk of data.

Please note that this technique may be used to inject code in another process so some Antivirus may warn about it.

**Final notes**

If Address Space Randomization is disabled you may not need to *inject* code in the process memory, you can call `CreateRemoteThread` with the address of a Windows kernel function with the same parameters (for example `LoadLibrary`). You can't do this with native applications (not linked to kernel32.dll).

You can't inject into system processes unless you have debug privileges for your process (with `AdjustTokenPrivileges`).

As alternative to the *fake window* you may create a suspended thread with a local variable, a TLS or stack entry used as data chunk. To find this thread you have to give it a name using, for example, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcb2z8hs.aspx) (but it's seldom applicable).

### The naive way

A poor man solution (but probably much more easy to implement and somehow even more robust) can be to use [ADS](https://web.archive.org/web/20190501042433/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/105763/how-to-use-ntfs-alternate-data-streams) to hide a small data file for each process you want to monitor (of course an ADS associated with its image then it's not applicable for services and `rundll`'ed processes unless you make it much more complicated).

- Iterate all processes and for each one create an ADS with a known name (and the process ID).
- Inside it you have to store the system startup time and all the data you need.

To read back that informations:

- Iterate all processes and check for that ADS, read it and compare the system startup time (if they mismatch then it means you found a *widow* ADS and it should be deleted.

Of course you have to take care of these *widows* so periodically you may need to check for them. Of course you can avoid this storing ALL these small chunk of data into a well-known location, your "reader" may check them all each time, deleting files no longer associated to a running process.